# How do Turing machines output $f(w)$ for $O(1)$ reductions?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, reductions, constant-time

When speaking about many-one Karp reductions, the definition is stated below:

$$
A \leq_P B \iff \exists f \colon \: \Sigma^* \mapsto \Gamma^* \: \text{such that} \: (w \in A \iff f(w) \in B)
$$

where $f$ is a polynomial time total computable function. But I think this raises a bit of an issue.

I have an [ongoing question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159623/are-any-known-problems-complete-for-p-under-o1-reductions) about P-complete problems under $O(1)$ reductions. So instead of Karp reductions, $f$ is a constant-time total computable function. This means that the Turing machine representing this function (which is single tape and one direction) must run in $O(1)$ time.

I am reading [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76791/do-there-exist-o1-complete-problems?rq=1) question which is similar to mine. It asks about $O(1)$ complete problems under $O(1)$ reductions. The accepted answer says

> I think that for O(1) problems, all languages are complete under "constant-time reductions" except $L = \Sigma^*$ and $L = \emptyset$

Here's my question: How can this total computable function, $f$, possibly run in constant time? If we go on the Turing machine model, where this $f$ is represented by a Turing machine computing it, the Turing machine would need to overwrite the tape. As there are $n$ letters in the tape, this would tape $O(n)$ time.

So how can this be? I think I may be misunderstanding something, or maybe reductions that are this strict aren't well defined?